# How to iterate over an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, iteration, rust

What can I do to iterate over an array of integers in Rust?

```
fn main () {

    let mut array: Vec<i64> = vec![2];

    for k in range(3, 13195) {
        for p in array.iter() {
           if (k % p != 0) {array.push(p)};
        }        
    }
}
```

Gives me the compiler error:

> rustc "Task2_minimalcode.rs" (im Verzeichnis: C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Rust - Project Euler)
>
> Task2_minimalcode.rs:7:14: 7:15 error: mismatched types:
>    expected `_`,
>       found `&i64`
>   (expected integral variable,
>       found &-ptr) [E0308]
>   Task2_minimalcode.rs:7      if (k % p != 0) {array.push(p)};
>                         ^
>   Task2_minimalcode.rs:7:34: 7:35 error: mismatched types:
>    expected `i64`,
>       found `&i64`
>   (expected i64,
>       found &-ptr) [E0308]
>
> Task2_minimalcode.rs:7      if (k % p != 0) {array.push(p)};
>                                                           ^
>   error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
>   Failed compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoth the error message:

> `error: mismatched types: expected i64, found &i64 (expected i64, found &-ptr)`

`Vec<T>::iter` gives you an iterator over `&T` (references to `T`).  If you don't intend to ever use the vec again, you can use `for p in array` or `for p in array.into_iter()`.  If you *do* want to use it again, you have several options:

- `&array` or `array.iter()`, and dereference `p` when using it.
- `array.iter().cloned()`
- `array.iter().map(|e| *e)` (effectively the same as above)

If all this talk about references doesn't make sense, you should probably read the section of the [Rust Book on Pointers](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/pointers.html).

Remember that you can trick the compiler into telling you the type of a variable like so: `let _:() = p;` -- the error message will contain the true type.

Comment: I need that vector again. "dereference p when using it." How do I do that?    &p doesn't work

Comment: `&p` takes a reference to `p`, `*p` dereferences a reference `p`.  You should probably read through the Rust Book; you won't get too far without understanding references in Rust: they're everywhere.

Comment: I know what reference/derefence is, but coming from managed code (Java) I have a hard time to decide when and where to use it :(.

Comment: Which is why I recommended the book; it's not about knowing what they are in the abstract, you need to understand how they're used.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a slice (which is a view into the `Vec`), you are getting *references to the items in the vector*, not the items themselves.

You can fix that in two equivalent ways.

```rust
// Mark the iteration variable as a reference
for &p in &array {
    if (k % p != 0) {
        array.push(p)
    };
}

// Dereference the iteration variable
for p in &array {
    if (k % *p != 0) {
        array.push(*p)
    };
}
```

However, then you run into the next problem: you can't modify the `Vec` while you are iterating over it! If you were allowed to, the vector might need to reallocate the memory that backs it, which would then in turn invalidate *all of the references in the iterator*. This is a strong selling point of Rust - it prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot like this!

Without knowing what you really want to do, here's one way of doing it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input_array = vec![2u64];
    let mut output_array = input_array.clone();

    for k in 3..13195 {
        for &p in &input_array {
            if k % p != 0 {
                output_array.push(p)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Difference between iter() and into_iter() on a shared, borrowed Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32234954/155423)

Comment: My goal is Euler project task 3 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=3), but it seems I need to get a better algorithm. I will overthink my program, thanks for your help :).

Comment: As far as I understand, the slice will yield values of type `i32`, correct? I want a slice of `usize` values, how to specify that?

Comment: @ArtemHevorhian the slice returns values of whatever type it is. In this case, it's a `Vec<u64>`, so subslices and indexed values will also use `u64`. Change your slice's type to change subslices and indexed values.