# Difference between iter() and into_iter() on a shared, borrowed Vec?

Tags: iterator, rust, shared

I am reading the [Rust 101 tutorial](https://www.ralfj.de/projects/rust-101/part04.html#section-5), where the author talks about shared borrowing with the example of a `Vec` object passed to a function. Below is a slightly adapted MWE of what the the tutorial is teaching. The interesting part is `v.iter()` in `vec_min`. The author writes:

> This time, we explicitly request an iterator for the vector `v`. The method `iter` borrows the vector it works on, and provides shared borrows of the elements.

But what happens if I use a `for ... in ...` construction on an object which is shared? According to [this blog post](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html), this implicit for loop uses `into_iter()`, taking ownership of `v`. But it cannot really take ownership of the `v` in that function, since it has only borrowed it to begin with, right?

Can somebody explain the difference between `into_iter()` and `iter()` applied to a borrowed object to me?

```
enum NumberOrNothing {
    Number(i32),
    Nothing,
}
use self::NumberOrNothing::{Number,Nothing};

impl NumberOrNothing {
    fn print(self) {
        match self {
            Nothing => println!("The number is: <nothing>"),
            Number(n) => println!("The number is: {}", n),
        };
    }
}

fn vec_min(v: &Vec<i32>) -> NumberOrNothing {
    fn min_i32(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        if a < b {a} else {b}
    }

    let mut min = Nothing;
    for e in v.iter() {
    //Alternatively implicitly and with *e replaced by e:
    //for e in v {
        min = Number(match min {
            Nothing => *e,
            Number(n) => min_i32(n, *e),
        });
    }
    min
}

pub fn main() {
    let vec = vec![18,5,7,2,9,27];
    let foo = Nothing;
    let min = vec_min(&vec);
    let min = vec_min(&vec);
    min.print();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a difference.

> it cannot really take ownership of the `v` in that function, since it has only borrowed it to begin with

It absolutely *can* take ownership of `v`, because that's a `&Vec`. Note the precise semantics here - you are taking ownership *of the reference*, not of the referred-to item.

If you check out the [implementors of `IntoIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), you can find:

```rust
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T>
```

And the [source for that](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.53.0/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs#L2451-L2458):

```rust
impl<'a, T, A: Allocator> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T, A> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

Surprise — it calls `iter`!

The same logic applies for `&mut vec` and `vec.iter_mut()`

Comment: Right, this is great, thanks a lot! I was also confused about `into_iter()` can work on both `&Vec` and `Vec`, but the source you reference explains it: there is an implementor for `Vec<T>` as well as for `&'a Vec<T>` and `&'a mut Vec<T>`. Very cool stuff! :)