# How to send to a tokio oneshot::channel when the Sender is in a Vec?

Tags: rust, vector, rust-tokio

I want to use a container to manage `tokio::oneshot::Sender`s. I'm using a `Vec`, but seems that values saved in `Vec` are references and I need to use `self`, not a reference, to call it:

```rust
use bytes::BytesMut;
use tokio::sync::oneshot;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum ChannelData {
    Video { timestamp: u32, data: BytesMut },
    Audio { timestamp: u32, data: BytesMut },
    MetaData {},
}

pub type PlayerPublisher = oneshot::Sender<ChannelData>;

pub struct Channel {
    player_producers: Vec<PlayerPublisher>, // consumers who subscribe this channel.
}

impl Channel {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            player_producers: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    async fn transmit(&mut self) {
        let b = BytesMut::new();
        let data = ChannelData::Video {
            timestamp: 234,
            data: b,
        };

        for i in self.player_producers {
            i.send(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The errors:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.player_producers` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:31:18
   |
31 |         for i in self.player_producers {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  move occurs because `self.player_producers` has type `Vec<tokio::sync::oneshot::Sender<ChannelData>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                  help: consider iterating over a slice of the `Vec<_>`'s content: `&self.player_producers`

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `data`
  --> src/lib.rs:32:20
   |
26 |         let data = ChannelData::Video {
   |             ---- move occurs because `data` has type `ChannelData`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
32 |             i.send(data);
   |                    ^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

How can I achieve my goal?

```rust
pub fn send(mut self, t: T) -> Result<(), T> {
    let inner = self.inner.take().unwrap();

    inner.value.with_mut(|ptr| unsafe {
        *ptr = Some(t);
    });

    if !inner.complete() {
        unsafe {
            return Err(inner.consume_value().unwrap());
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (**and their versions**), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `send` requires ownership of the oneshot channel. To get that ownership, you can take ownership of the container. In this case, the easiest way is to take ownership of the `Channel`:

```rust
async fn transmit(self) { // Changed to `self`
    for i in self.player_producers {
        let data = ChannelData::Video {
            timestamp: 234,
            data: BytesMut::new(),
        };
        if i.send(data).is_err() {
            panic!("Unable to send data");
        }
    }
}
```

Other options are to [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) the collection:

```rust
for i in self.player_producers.drain(..) {
```

Or [swap the collection with an empty one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```rust
use std::mem;
for i in mem::take(&mut self.player_producers) {
```

In each case, the `data` payload has to be constructed (or cloned) each time it is sent.

See also:

- [Difference between iter() and into_iter() on a shared, borrowed Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32234954/155423)
- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)
- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)

Comment: The first answer is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

A Tokio oneshot sender can only send a single message, so `send` will consume the `Sender`. To call `send` from within a `Vec`, you first have to *remove* it. The way to remove all elements from a `&mut Vec` while iterating over the them is to [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Drain.html) it:

```
for i in self.player_producers.drain(..) {
    i.send(data);
}
```

Your other error is from `data` being consumed by the call to `send`. Since you want to send the same data to multiple senders, you'll have to `clone` it:

```
i.send(data.clone());
```

Be mindful of the warning that `send` returns a `Result`.