# Why does the compiler expect a double reference instead of a reference when treating a slice as an iterator?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I want to create a struct that accepts both a `Vec<String>` and a `&[&str]` (among other types):

```rust
pub struct Channel<I, T>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: AsRef<str>,
{
    pub name: String,
    pub instruments: I,
}
```

When passing a `Vec<String>`, it works as expected:

```rust
pub struct Response {
    pub channels: Channel<Vec<String>, String>,
}
```

But when passing a `&[&str]`:

```rust
pub struct Request<'a> {
    pub channels: Channel<&'a [&'a str], &'a str>,
}
```

... I get the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&'a [&'a str] as IntoIterator>::Item == &'a str`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:19
   |
11 |     pub channels: Channel<&'a [&'a str], &'a str>,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `str`, found `&str`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&'a str`
              found reference `&&'a str`
note: required by a bound in `Channel`
  --> src/lib.rs:3:21
   |
1  | pub struct Channel<I, T>
   |            ------- required by a bound in this
2  | where
3  |     I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Channel`
```

Why is `T` treated as a `&&'a str` in that case?

The solution is to use the following notation instead, but I really want to know why writing `T` as `&'a str`, which it actually is, does not work.

```rust
pub struct Request<'a> {
    pub channels: Channel<&'a [&'a str], &'a &'a str>,
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `&[T]` implements `Iterator<Item = T>`? (hint: it doesn't).

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423); [Difference between iter() and into_iter() on a shared, borrowed Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32234954/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Have a look at the [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-IntoIterator) of `IntoIterator` for `&'a [T]`. What is `T` in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IntoIterator` for `&[T]` yields references: `&T`, so since your slice type is `&str`, the iterator `Item` is `&&str`.

Also, your code can be simplified by not taking in the second generic parameter. You can use `I::Item` to constrain on the iterator type:

```
pub struct Channel<I>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    pub name: String,
    pub instruments: I,
}

let channels: Channel<Vec<String>>;
let channels: Channel<&[&str]>;
```